# How to extract text and images from a pdf file and link them together in PDFbox 2.0.27?

Tags: java, pdfbox

everyone!
Could you please help me figure out how to extract text and attach images to it? For example, in a file there is text describing a picture, and a picture under the text. There are many pictures in a PDF file, they can be of different sizes. There can also be several pictures with descriptions on one page.
[image]

First I extracted all the text, then I extracted all the images with reference to the page. And now I can't figure out how to link them.
I have a theory that I need to use the metadata of the text and images, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I use Java 11, PDFbox 2.0.27

```
public class PdfFileReaderService implements FileReaderService {
    @Override
    public String getAllTextFromFile(String filepath) {
        try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(filepath))) {
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            return stripper.getText(document);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't get text from file: " + filepath, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<Integer, List<RenderedImage>> getAllImageFromFile(String pathToFile) {
        Map<Integer, List<RenderedImage>> images = new HashMap<>();
        try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pathToFile))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                PDPage page = document.getPage(i);
                List<RenderedImage> pageImages = getImagesFromResources(page.getResources());
                images.put(i, pageImages.isEmpty() ? new ArrayList<>() : pageImages);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't get images from file: " + pathToFile);
        }
        return images;
    }


    private List<RenderedImage> getImagesFromResources(PDResources resources) throws IOException {
        List<RenderedImage> images = new ArrayList<>();
        for (COSName xObjectName : resources.getXObjectNames()) {
            PDXObject xObject = resources.getXObject(xObjectName);
            if (xObject instanceof PDFormXObject) {
                images.addAll(getImagesFromResources(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources()));
            } else if (xObject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                BufferedImage image = ((PDImageXObject) xObject).getImage();
                images.add(image);
            }
        }
        return images;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless your pdf is properly tagged, it is unclear for a content extractor whether an image is associated with the text above, the text below, or both. If you know that in your case images always are associated with the text above, you merely need to extract both text and images with coordinates and try to match them by those coordinates.

Comment: @mkl I'm a beginner at this and can't figure out how to extract text coordinates

Comment: @KJ I have a 2049-page pdf that describes car repair procedures. I have parsed this pdf into steps. Where one item is, for example, “2. Remove the battery and battery tray(A).” is one step. If the step has a picture, I need to find this picture and add its ID to the mediaRef field (List<Media>). I uploaded the images earlier. I named the images with the page number + the sequence number of the image on the page (81_image_1). Now, I think that the images should be loaded at the moment when you attach it to the step.

Comment: @KJ I found the coordinates of a picture on a page.
Could you please tell me which character coordinates I need to look for to compare with the coordinator of the image?

Comment: I was able to find a link to the last character of the string and a link to a picture to see what I'm talking about. 
https://i.postimg.cc/JzFXCWYq/1234.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I found the coordinates of all the last characters of the text lines on the page and compared them with the coordinates of the picture. If the Y coordinates of the image are less than the Y coordinates of the previous line and greater than the next line, then the image must be between these lines :)

Comment: Can you update the solution here ?

Comment: The inability to express complexity in simpler words is the hallmark sign of an average developer. Anyway, I found an efficient way to retrieve text + images with their relative positions in the order described in the PDF (irrespective of the style or formatting of the PDF). Thought would share, but seems like you are content with your "smart" solution. Good luck.